# "Any" size class missing in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I'm a little confused when seeing the new interface builder's size class options in Xcode 8 beta. I used to build my apps' UI by first design them in "Any" size class and then do some custom adjustments in the other ones. Is the workflow supposed to be changed in this new version of Xcode?

[image: Any size class in Xcode 7]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way to do this has changed slightly in the new version of Xcode. It should build for "any-any" automatically. Have a look at this WWDC video that I think explains it in detail. There is also a part 2, so watch that if you need to.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/222/

Hope I could help,
Zack

Comment: Thank you. The video explains it very well.

Comment: Also see: [What's New in Auto Layout, WWDC 2016-236](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/236/)

Comment: If you don't want to see the whole video you can skip directly to the Demo at 19:00 which pretty much sums it all up.

Answer (score 22):

The UI to select the size classes has changed in xcode 8. Now it is as follows:

Any constraints that you add without selecting **Vary for Traits** options will be considered as for all the size classes( **Any Any** previously)

[image]

To add a constraint to a specific size class add it by selecting:

- The device at the bottom  and by selecting **Vary for Traits**
  options of that size class.
- When you are adding constraints to a specific size class the bar
  turns blue as below

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's what I had learned from the WWDC 2016 video

Answer (score 2):

To convert from the old Any by Any to the new Trait layout, go through each of your View Controllers and update all frames.

[image: Screen shot]